# MapKit iOS Swift Zoom Issues

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, overlay

I added multiple overlays in the map. When I try to zoom in/out I have this issue:

- thread #6: tid = 0x6fdb, 0x000000010b5757a5 MapKit`MKPolylineCreatePathWithPoints + 44, queue = 'com.apple.root.default-qos', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

  - frame #0: 0x000000010b5757a5 MapKit`MKPolylineCreatePathWithPoints + 44
    frame #1: 0x000000010b56e839 MapKit`-[MKPolylineRenderer drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:] + 147
    frame #2: 0x000000010b56a5a2 MapKit`__47-[MKOverlayRenderer overlay:drawKey:inContext:]_block_invoke + 670
    frame #3: 0x000000010b56a661 MapKit`_worldsForBounds28687 + 58
    frame #4: 0x000000010b56a2e9 MapKit`-[MKOverlayRenderer overlay:drawKey:inContext:] + 307
    frame #5: 0x0000000116542bf9 VectorKit`__40-[VKRasterOverlayTileSource _queueDraw:]_block_invoke + 441
    frame #6: 0x000000010e463e5d libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    frame #7: 0x000000010e48449b libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
    frame #8: 0x000000010e46cbef libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1829
    frame #9: 0x000000010e46c4c5 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread3 + 111
    frame #10: 0x000000010e7bc68f libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 1129
    frame #11: 0x000000010e7ba365 libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 13

what could be the posible issue? My code is as follows.

**Code:**

```
 public func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {

    var overlaysArch : Dictionary<MKPolygon, MKCircleRenderer> = Dictionary<MKPolygon, MKCircleRenderer>();
    let az = arrayAz?.first
    let azSize = arrayAz?.count

    _ = names?.first

    _ = 0

    if (azSize != 0 && names?.count != 0) {

        if (overlay.isKindOfClass(MKPolygon)) {

            let path = mapDrawPolygon.drawArch(az!);

            let polygon = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            polygon.path = path
            polygon.overlay.title

            let over : CustomOverlay = overlay as! CustomOverlay;

            overlaysArch[over] = polygon;

            return polygon
        }
    }
    return MKPolylineRenderer()
}
```

Comment: share your code please

Comment: @UmairAfzal I have shared code above